# Mobile Responding Weirdly

Tags: android, html, css

So I'm setting up something extremely simple: a webpage with two containers and one sign-up form. The containers are otherwise empty, except for a background image set and configured with CSS. I'm trying to get this webpage to respond differently based on screen sizes with media queries, and for my desktop, it works fine; when I resize the page to (for example) anything below 720px, the background images in the containers adjust accordingly and predictably. Here's where the problem begins: it doesn't respond on my mobile device.

I'm using the Galaxy S3 as my starting point. Its resolution is 720x1280px. But it seems as though the media query is having no effect on the mobile browser.

Here's how it appears on desktops and laptops:

```
#header {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  background:url(".../header.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Here's the media query configured for the Samsung Galaxy S3:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 720px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

#header {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  background:url(".../header.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-size:500px auto;
}

}
```

I have already added the viewport tag to my `<head>` but I'm still not getting the desired response from my coding. Am I doing something wrong? Should I try for another device as a benchmark?

Answer (score 0):

Max-height is going to correlate with 1280px, not 720px. The default orientation of the Galaxy S3, at least in Chrome, is going to be portrait. Set max-width:720px.

I never use the keyword "only" as I had trouble getting it to work back when media queries were newer. Try a query like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

Or keep it simple and do:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){

}
```

BTW it's best practice not to use max-width that often. You want to start styling your smallest screen and use min-width to move up to larger screens.

And it's possible due to the pixel density that Galaxy is reporting a much smaller screen-width. It says 360px here: http://www.mydevice.io

Comment: Thanks, but this proved to be unsuccessful.

Comment: Set an obvious rule like {background-color:red;} to confirm that the ruleset is working.